# Access generated Android R class from native code

Tags: android, resources, java-native-interface, native-code

I'm wondering if there is a way to access R class attribute from native code, I need it to read some generated ID that may change every time i do a clean build of my project and I would prefer not to pass them manually to the native part.

**EDIT**
As suggested from @trashkalmar here is the solution:

```
static const char* const strClassName = "your/app/package/R$string";
clazz = env->FindClass(strClassName);
if (clazz == NULL) {
    LOGE("Can't find class %s\n", strClassName);
    return result;
}
jfieldID field = env->GetStaticFieldID(clazz , "you_string_resource", "I");
jint value = env->GetStaticIntField(clazz, field);
```

Comment: Please provide more detail, what are you trying to implement actually? It would be easy to understand exactly if you share your problem exactly.

Comment: It is a common problem: I would like to access to all R attribute without having to pass it manually to the native part, something like the way you can access to assets resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access your R class and read its fields as any other classes.

Comment: It was really so simple... Thanks for the hint! :)